# Convert an object array of object arrays to a two dimensional array of object

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a third party library returning an object array of object arrays that I can stuff into an object[]:

```
object[] arr = myLib.GetData(...);
```

The resulting array consists of object[] entries, so you can think of the return value as some kind of recordset with the outer array representing the rows and the inner arrays containing the field values where some fields might not be filled (a jagged array). To access the individual fields I have to cast like:

```
int i = (int) ((object[])arr[row])[col];//access a field containing an int
```

Now as I'm lazy I want to access the elements like this:

```
int i = (int) arr[row][col];
```

To do this I use the following Linq query:

```
object[] result = myLib.GetData(...);
object[][] arr = result.Select(o => (object[])o ).ToArray();
```

I tried using a simple cast like `object[][] arr = (object[][])result;` but that fails with a runtime error.

Now, my questions:

- Is there a simpler way of doing this? I have the feeling that some
  nifty cast should do the trick?
- Also I am worried about performance
  as I have to reshape a lot of data just to save me some casting, so I
  wonder if this is really worth it?

**EDIT:** 
Thank you all for the speedy answers.
@James: I like your answer wrapping up the culprit in a new class, but the drawback is that I always have to do the Linq wrapping when taking in the source array and the indexer needs both row and col values `int i = (int) arr[row, col];`  (I need to get a complete row as well like `object[] row = arr[row];`, sorry didn't post that in the beginning).
@Sergiu Mindras: Like James, i feel the extension method a bit dangerous as it would apply to all `object[]` variables.
@Nair: I chose your answer for my implementation, as it does not need using the Linq wrapper and I can access both individual fields using `int i = (int) arr[row][col];` or an entire row using `object[] row = arr[row];`
@quetzalcoatl and @Abe Heidebrecht: Thanks for the hints on `Cast<>()`.

**Conclusion:** I wish I could choose both James' and Nair's answer, but as I stated above, Nair's solution gives me (I think) the best flexibility and performance.
I added a function that will 'flatten' the internal array using the above Linq statement because I have other functions that need to be fed with such a structure.

Here is how I (roughly) implemented it (taken from Nair's solution:

public class CustomArray
        {
            private object[] data;
            public CustomArray(object[] arr)
            {
                data = arr;
            }

```
        //get a row of the data
        public object[] this[int index]
        { get { return (object[]) data[index]; } }

        //get a field from the data
        public object this[int row, int col]
        { get { return ((object[])data[row])[col]; } }

        //get the array as 'real' 2D - Array
        public object[][] Data2D()
        {//this could be cached in case it is accessed more than once
            return data.Select(o => (object[])o ).ToArray()
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var ca = new CustomArray(new object[] { 
                      new object[] {1,2,3,4,5 },
                      new object[] {1,2,3,4 },
                      new object[] {1,2 } });
            var row = ca[1]; //gets a full row
            int i = (int) ca[2,1]; //gets a field
            int j = (int) ca[2][1]; //gets me the same field
            object[][] arr = ca.Data2D(); //gets the complete array as 2D-array
        }

    }
```

So - again - thank you all! It always is a real pleasure and enlightenment to use this site.

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Comment: The most expensive operation here is the unboxing from `object` to `int` (and other types), which seems inevitable since your lib only returns `object[]`. Are you sure that it doesn't provide a typed interface?

Comment: what does var[] arr = myLib.GetData(...); give you in this case?

Comment: @Andre: The returned data is made up of different types, and, no, there is not typed interface as the function basically returns the result of a select statement that can contain many differently typed fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few similar answer posted which does something similar. This differ only if you want to acess like

```
int i = (int) arr[row][col];
```

To demonstrate the idea

```
   public class CustomArray
        {
            private object[] _arr;
            public CustomArray(object[] arr)
            {
                _arr = arr;
            }

            public object[] this[int index]
            {
                get
                {
                    // This indexer is very simple, and just returns or sets 
                    // the corresponding element from the internal array. 
                    return (object[]) _arr[index];
                }
            }
            static void Main()
            {
                var c = new CustomArray(new object[] { new object[] {1,2,3,4,5 }, new object[] {1,2,3,4 }, new object[] {1,2 } });
                var a =(int) c[1][2]; //here a will be 4 as you asked.
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You could create a wrapper class to hide the ugly casting e.g.

```
public class DataWrapper
{
    private readonly object[][] data;

    public DataWrapper(object[] data)
    {
        this.data = data.Select(o => (object[])o ).ToArray();
    }

    public object this[int row, int col]
    {
        get { return this.data[row][col]; }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var data = new DataWrapper(myLib.GetData(...));
int i = (int)data[row, col];
```

There is also the opportunity to make the wrapper generic e.g. `DataWrapper<int>`, however, I wasn't sure if your data collection would be all of the same type, returning `object` keeps it generic enough for you to decide what data type cast is needed.

Comment: An idea: with your current solution, everytime the user calls `data[1, 1]`, an unboxing will be computed. So, why don't you convert ahead the `object[]` to `object[][]` using the code OP presented?

Comment: I'd argue about that unboxing. If the items were read many times, it in fact will speed up the overall usage. But, if the set of the items are just read once and immediatelly processed, the pre-unboxing will hit the performance with a possible higher memory usage for no real gain. Think about datastream generated on the fly as the data is fetched from the database. Iterate over and cache million of `object[]` just not to unbox them twice..? That's an optimization that should be strictly tailored to the exact use case.  Please do not suggest that "just because it's better".

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl it's a fair point, however, going on the assumption that the OP *is* going to be reading all the information then it's probably the right way to go. Let me update the solution so it's flexible for both scenarios...

Comment: I meant read-once (not so worth the effort) versus read-manytimes (worth the effort Nth times). I've noticed that the toplevel dataobject is a `object[]`, so all the data is in memory already, but caching effectively doubles the memory for toplevel array. That's the only warning I wanted to add! As I already wrote, I like that solution.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl "*But, if the set of items are just read once and immediately processed, the pre-unboxing will hit the performance*" - surely if *all* the items are going to be read at least once the pre-unboxing would be better? Otherwise you would be unboxing *per index*.

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully grasp whever it is rhetorical question or not, so I'll pass and just note that not "at least once" but "several times" (as for exactly one read it's not worth it), and even better, that should be "significantly many times so the possible extra memory consumption is tolerable". Please excuse me the nitpicking. I think that all is obvious after what was already said and your question/comment confused me.

Answer (score 1):

(1) This probably could be done in short and easy form with `dynamic` keyword, but you'll use compile-time checking. But considering that you use object[], that's a small price:

```
dynamic results = obj.GetData();
object something = results[0][1];
```

I've not checked it with a compiler though.

(2) instead of `Select(o => (type)o)` there's a dedicated `Cast<>` function:

```
var tmp = items.Select(o => (object[])o).ToArray();
var tmp = items.Cast<object[]>().ToArray();
```

They are almost the same. I'd guess that Cast is a bit faster, but again, I've not checked that.

(3) Yes, reshaping in that way will affect the performance somewhat, depending mostly on the amount of items. The impact will be the larger the more elements you have. That's mostly related to .ToArray as it will enumerate all the items and it will make an additional array. Consider this:

```
var results = ((object[])obj.GetData()).Cast<object[]>();
```

The 'results' here are of type `IEnumerable<object[]>` and the difference is that it will be enumerated lazily, so the extra iteration over all elements is gone, the temporary extra array is gone, and also the overhead is minimal - similar to manual casting of every element, which you'd do anyways.. But - you lose the ability to index over the topmost array. You can loop/`foreach` over it, but you cannot index/`[123]` it.

EDIT:

The James's wrapper way is probably the best in terms of overall performance. I like it the most for readability, but that's personal opinion. Others may like LINQ more. But, I like it. I'd suggest James' wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You could use extension method:

```
static int getValue(this object[] arr, int col, int row)
{
    return (int) ((object[])arr[row])[col];
}
```

And retrieve by

```
int requestedValue = arr.getValue(col, row);
```

No idea for arr[int x][int y] syntax.

*EDIT*

Thanks James for your observation

You can use a nullable int so you don't get an exception when casting.

So, the method will become:

```
static int? getIntValue(this object[] arr, int col, int row)
{
    try
    {
    int? returnVal = ((object[])arr[row])[col] as int;
    return returnVal;
    }
    catch(){ return null; }
}
```

And can be retrieved by

```
int? requestedValue = arr.getIntValue(col, row);
```

This way you get a nullable object and all encountered exceptions force return null

Comment: I'd argue that this is misuse of an extension method. It should be generic enough to use on any instance of `object[]`, in this scenario you are assuming all `object[]` will contain an inner `object[]` and be of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ Cast operator instead of Select...

```
object[][] arr = result.Cast<object[]>().ToArray()
```

This is a little less verbose, but should be nearly identical performance wise. Another way is to do it manually:

```
object[][] arr = new object[result.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    arr[i] = (object[])result[i];
```